RainTPL3 if or check
I need to check two variables in RainTPL3, and it should only show them if the either one is true. So I would want something that checks them:
I already tried the following, after asking ChatGPT, since I could not find any good documentation sources about RainTPL:
{if="$var1!='00:00' || $var2!='00:00'}
<p>
{$var1} - {$var2}
</p>
{/if}


What's the issue then? Do you get an error? Or the test doesn't work as expected in some cases (if so, show the test cases with input data for each variable)? Or something else? You forgot to tell us the specific problem you're experiencing. See also [ask]

First, I hope you are not starting a new project with this template engine, or even testing the waters with it, just to try something, and instead you are forced to use this because it is legacy code. With all due respect to the author of the system, it appears to be for all intents and purposes abandoned. Except for a bug fix in 2019 there have been no commits of consequence for almost a decade now.

You are missing the closing double quote for the if statement:
{if="$var1!='00:00' || $var2!='00:00'"}
<p>
{$var1} - {$var2}
</p>
{/if}

